# Use FixtureAdapter for tests only

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

How can I make ember user the FixtureAdapter when running tests?

I thought the code below would do it, but it doesn't, api calls are still being made.

// tests/helpers/start-app.js

```
Ember.run(function(){
  App = Application.create(attributes);
  App.setupForTesting();
  App.injectTestHelpers();

  // .create doesn't work either
  App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend({
    queryFixtures: function(fixtures, query) {
      console.log('querying fixtures');
      var key = Object.keys(query)[0];
      return fixtures.filterBy(key, +query[key]);
    }
  });
});
```

Within the `setup()` test method I can see that the custom fixture adapter is set.

```
module('Acceptance: AssignmentMenu', {
  setup: function() {
    App = startApp();

    // verify the FixtureAdapter is being used 
    var adapter = App.ApplicationAdapter.create();
    console.log('queryFixtures => ', adapter.queryFixtures);  // method does exist

    session = App.__container__.lookup('service:session');
  },
  teardown: function() {
    Ember.run(App, 'destroy');
  }
});
```

Here is the `store.find` call that is resulting in a call to the external API

```
import AppRoute from "./app";

export default AppRoute.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('class').then(function(classes) {
      return classes.sortBy('name');
    });
  }
});
```

All of the above passes the tests if the setting of the adapter is done within the `app/adapaters/application.js` file, so all the required fixtures are in place.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't overwriting the application adapter somewhere else in your code?  I'd guess in non testing mode you're not using the fixture adapter.

Comment: Positive.  The additional code that I added above shows a check if the  FixturesAdapter is in place, which it is, but doesn't seem to work.